# Get second child element by using child index in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get the second child of the div

```
<div id="container">
   <h1>title</h1>
   <h1>another title</h1>
   <h3>tag</h3>
   <p>details</p>
</div>
```

I don't want to access it using it's attribute name.  e.g $("#container h1:nth-of-type(1)");
Is there a way to access child elements of container using the indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, you want:

$('#container h1:nth-of-type(1)')

Example test: https://jsfiddle.net/9u0xwsf6/

```
var item = $('#container h1:nth-of-type(1)').html();
alert("Item Data:" + item);
```

Comment: I modified your code with the help of other guys who answered and so I ended up with.. 

var item = $('#container > *:nth-child(1)').html();
alert("Item Data:" + item);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container').children('h1').get(1)
```

Comment: $('#container').children().get(1) Can I use this?
I don't want to refer to h1

Comment: Yes, without argument it gets all children.

Answer (score 0):

There is another selector you can use `#container > *:nth-child(2)`.. `*` to select all elements

```css
#container > *:nth-child(2){
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <h1>title</h1>
   <h1>another title</h1>
   <h3>tag</h3>
   <p>details</p>
</div>
```

> **Note:** `:nth-child()` index starts from 1 .. so to select the second
>   element use 2 and so on..